# Using Dagger2 with GWT in IntelliJ IDEA - how to avoid compile whole Maven module

Tags: intellij-idea, gwt, dagger-2

I have a GWT application which uses Dagger 2 for dependency injection.

Dagger2 works ok but what I find is I have to do `clean install` on the Maven module whenever I change injection.

Is there a way to re-generate dagger2 classes on file save instead? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

At the moment I take these steps to trigger dagger2 regen:

1. Stop GWT dev server
2. clean install the affected Maven module
3. Start GWT dev server

Comment: You should never need to install, you rarely will need to clean. You can use package or verify instead of install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the codeserver started (either `gwt:devmode` or `gwt:codeserver`), compile your project <kbd>⌘+F9</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+F9</kbd>. This will fire your processor and generate new sources. Then reload your page to fire code-server compilation.